# Pandas unique doest not work on groupby object when applied on several columns

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, python-3.7

Lets' say I have a dataframe with 3 columns, one containing the groups, and I would to collect the collections of values in the 2 other columns for each group.

Normally I would use the pandas.groupby function and apply the unique method. Well this does not work if unique is applied on more than 1 column...

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4],
    'param1': [1, 5, 8, np.nan, 2, 3, np.nan],
    'param2': [5,6,9,10,11,12,1]
})
```

Apply unique on 1 column:

```
df.groupby('group')['param1'].unique()
```

```
group
1         [1.0, 5.0]
2              [8.0]
3    [nan, 2.0, 3.0]
4              [nan]
Name: param1, dtype: object
```

Apply unique on 2 columns:

```
df.groupby('group')[['param1', 'param2']].unique()
```

I get an AttributeError:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'unique'
```

Instead I would expect this dataframe:

```
    param1  param2
group       
1   [1.0, 5.0]  [5, 6]
2   [8.0]   [9]
3   [nan, 2.0, 3.0]     [10,11,12]
4   [nan]   [1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason of error is `unique` working only for `Series`, so is only implemented [`SeriesGroupBy.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique.html).

---

For me working [`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) with convert to list:

```
df = df.groupby('group')[['param1', 'param2']].agg(lambda x: list(x.unique()))
print (df)
                param1        param2
group                               
1           [1.0, 5.0]        [5, 6]
2                [8.0]           [9]
3      [nan, 2.0, 3.0]  [10, 11, 12]
4                [nan]           [1]
```

Comment: not weird, in my opinion, because unique is meant for series/single array items. I'm guessing the list tells pandas to treat each item as a series; just a guess, probably have to look at the internals to understand why that works

Comment: @sammywemmy - ya, I think weird error more not clear what is problem from error, because if use `agg` then there are passed columns like `Series`.

Answer (score 3):

```
df = df.groupby('group').agg({'param1': 'unique',
                         'param2': 'unique'})
print(df)

                param1        param2
group                               
1           [1.0, 5.0]        [5, 6]
2                [8.0]           [9]
3      [nan, 2.0, 3.0]  [10, 11, 12]
4                [nan]           [1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have many groups, and you want the same behavior (i.e unique) then we can use `.stack` before the groupby so you don't need to call each column manually.

```
df.set_index('group').stack(dropna=False).groupby(level=[0,1]).unique().unstack()

                param1              param2
group                                     
1           [1.0, 5.0]          [5.0, 6.0]
2                [8.0]               [9.0]
3      [nan, 2.0, 3.0]  [10.0, 11.0, 12.0]
4                [nan]               [1.0]
```